# Jasper Server Error - Permission denied Error while printing reports

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

All of a sudden we are getting below error while we try to print reports. Does any one has any clue what could be the cause for this?

Where can I get specific error details about this error.

Thanks for your help!

Jaspersoft 5.0

The server has encountered an error. Please excuse the inconvenience.

Error Message com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSExceptionWrapper: Permission denied

Error Message java.io.IOException: Permission denied

Answer (score 1):

Jaspersoft uses a temporary location within Apache Tomcat to save reports as they are rendered. There is a chance something changed on this directory. 
**tomcat\temp**

You can also check the log files to be sure.
**tomcat\logs**

Look for the localhost log (not necessarily catalina nor access log)